# Why Erlang allows an atom to include bare @ signs? Does it have a practical usage?

Tags: erlang

The Erlang official user's guide (http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id67942) says:

> An atom is to be enclosed in single quotes (`'`) if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters, underscore (`_`), or `@`.

Why Erlang allows an atom to include bare `@` signs? Does it have a practical usage, or any historical meaning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it have a practical usage

Yes it does. Node names in Erlang are represented as atoms and they contain an `@` separating the name and host. Allowing `@` in atoms without single quotes makes it convenient to type them (unless they contain other special characters like `.` or `-`).

```
$ erl
1> foo@bar.
foo@bar
```

Comment: It wasn't always that way.  I'm still in the habit of quoting them because of past experience.